# Smooth data for a geom_area graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have data that looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(
    x = 1:20,
    y = c(4, 4, 2, 1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1, 7, 8, 9, 9, 2)
)
```

Graphed, it looks like this:

```
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_area()
```

[image]

But the graph is really jarring. How might I smooth out the jagged edges to something like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    stat_smooth(geom = 'area')`

Comment: Adjust with `span`. Love it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on Axeman's comment: smooth can be controlled by the `span` parameter.

Example 1:

```
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    # original, delete if desired
    geom_area(alpha = 1/2) + 
    stat_smooth(
        geom = 'area', method = 'loess', span = 1/3,
        alpha = 1/2, fill = "red") + 
    labs(title = "Smooth with `span = 1/3`")
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_area(alpha = 1/2) + 
    # original, delete if desired
    stat_smooth(
        geom = 'area', method = 'loess', span = 7/10,
        alpha = 1/2, fill = "blue") + 
    labs(title = "Smooth with `span = 7/10`")
```

[image]